# Make ImageButtons rescale to fit the edge of the screen

Tags: java, android

My ImageButton scales great but for layout purposes I want it to hit the sides of the screen, how would I do this?

ImageButton Rescaling code:

```
public void getScreenRes() {
    DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenwidth = display.widthPixels;
    int screenheight = display.heightPixels;
    double buttonheight = screenwidth / 2.66666667;
    int buttonheightint= (int) Math.round(buttonheight);
    ImageButton fbLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.facebookLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams fb = fbLogin.getLayoutParams();
    fb.width = screenwidth;
    fb.height = buttonheightint;
    fbLogin.setLayoutParams(fb);
    ImageButton instaLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.instagramLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams insta = instaLogin.getLayoutParams();
    insta.width = screenwidth;
    insta.height = buttonheightint;
    instaLogin.setLayoutParams(insta);
}
```

XML:

```
   <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
       android:background="@drawable/facebook"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:id="@+id/facebookLogin"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:onClick="facebookLogin"
       />
   <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/instagram"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/facebookLogin"
        android:id="@+id/instagramLogin"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:onClick="instagramLogin"
        />
```

And this is what I want, where the red lines are unoccupied space I want to fill with the imagebutton:

[image]

Comment: usually android:layout_AlignParentLeft="true" should do the trick and android:layout_width="match_parent"...it´s possible that You have to set another scaleType, maybe fitXY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fede Bucich mentioned above using

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

will make the button match the width of its parent view, but for the image you have specified a scaleType to "fitCenter" which will maintain the original aspect ratio of the source image and center it, instead use "fitXY" to stretch to both x and y axis.

Comment: This makes no difference either.

Comment: have you set the layout width to match parent and set the scaleType to fitXY? If that's the case check whether you have set a padding or margin value for any of the top level parent.

Comment: from looking at you layout you probably have set a padding or margin for the root view which is the top most view

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried widh the following?

```
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html):

`FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)`

Answer (score 0):

Change you ImageButton width to "match_parent" and scaleType to "fitXY" like the following :

```
   <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
       android:background="@drawable/facebook"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:id="@+id/facebookLogin"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:onClick="facebookLogin"/>
```

but this will work only if the `layout` that contains the `ImageButtons`  has `layout_width` equals `match_parent`